# where can i find VARIANT type codes? (vboxapi problem)

Tags: python, windows, com, virtualbox, variant

I'm using `vboxapi` through the COM, and I noticed a bug... calling `IMedium.CreateBaseStorage` as they have defined it yields an error, "Invalid VARIANT type: 20". I changed the value of 20 to 19, which was the VARIANT of the other (integer) parameter:

```
        def _patch_createBaseStorage(self, aLogicalSize, aVariant):
            from win32com.client import Dispatch
            LCID = 0x0
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743844, LCID, 1, (9, 0),
                                            ((19, 1), #used to be: (20, 1),
                                             (19, 1)),aLogicalSize
        , aVariant)
    if ret is not None:
        ret = Dispatch(ret, u'CreateBaseStorage', '{A163C98F-8635-4AA8-B770-A9941737F3EF}', UnicodeToString=0)
    return ret
```

however, this doesn't work, as the value is the size of the hard drive in bytes, meaning it can be at most 4 gigabytes, while I need to make 80, 120, 250 GB hard drives, etc.

So what's the VARIANT type of an 8-byte integer? I assume it is `VT_I8`, but what is the numerical value? And for future reference, where can I find them?

If the value is 20 then i'm screwed, since that is the value that is failing... in that case, anyone else have advice?

Comment: also posted this on the [virtualbox forums](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=39552#).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380072.aspx) is one source (table at the bottom).